# Build and use Oboe Resampler in Android

Tags: android, audio, oboe

I'm trying to integrate Oboe Resampler in my android application.

https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/src/flowgraph/resampler

The idea is to convert ByteBuffer of audio that comes with 32000 sample rate in audio with 44100 sample rate.

How I should build the C++ library and how should I integrate and do the resampling in my android application? Can someone share some snippet or link to the already built version of this c++ library?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build the resampler to do this as it's already in Oboe. You can just open an Oboe audio stream with a sample rate of 32000 frames/sec and switch on resampling.

Here's how:

```
// Create a stream builder
oboe::AudioStreamBuilder builder;

// Specify the rate at which you'll be supplying audio frames
builder.setSampleRate(32000);

// Switch on the resampler by specifying the resampling quality - this is a tradeoff between CPU and quality. 
builder.setSampleRateConversionQuality(SampleRateConversionQuality::Medium);
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#creating-an-audio-stream) for setting up a data callback where you can write your `ByteBuffer` into the audio stream buffer.